# how can i use python to tag specific sellers with specific lables

Tags: python, mysql

i need to answer the following question:

Write a script to show sellers that generate more than $300 GMV with "Tier 1" and the rest with "Tier 2"

i have two sql databases

[sellers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luL8l.png)

order:

[Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkkxI.png)

i need to use python to tag sellers who generate more than $300 GMV as Tier 1 and anything else as Tier 2, but am unsure how to do this - i would normally use a SUM wrapped around a case statment to make the proper calculations and tags in mysql, but i believe this is different in python

any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0):

create one more column in the sellers database adding all the amount of that seller. using that value make the Tier column.